# Proper use of AddWithValue in C# to Db method

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to do the following:

```
 public static int GetJobStatusByNumber(int jobNumber)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"select STATUS  from JOB
                                where JOB_NUMBER = @jobNumber";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobNumber", jobNumber);

            int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return result;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thouht I can add the varible 'jobNumber' to the query by using 'AddWithValue' but I'm getting a cast error

**Message: System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid.**

What's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: is `STATUS` an integer? `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column value from the first row, regardless of type, so if it gets back, say, a string, then the cast to `int` will fail.

Comment: Oh, true. Changed to string. An oversight...;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExecuteScalar() returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

2 scenarios are possible:

1. the first column is not a int.
2. the query return 0 rows - in that case ExecuteScalar() will return null.

for point 1 - make sure that the first column is an int.

for point 2 - make sure you have rows. possible solution will be:

```
var result = 0;
var tempResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (tempResult != null) {
    result = (int)tempResult;
}
```